# Does Hibernate come in a 64 bit version?

Tags: hibernate

Hi does anyone know if Hibernate comes in a 64 bit version or do I have to build it myself?  If anyone has a link I would appreciate it.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate is written entirely in Java, threfore it can't have 32-bit or 64-bit versions. The same version of Hibernate can run on both 32-bit and 64-bit JVMs.